# How to boot on android if on windows 10?

Tags: windows, dual-boot

I got a myphone my51 tablet, it has a dual boot feature for android and windows 10.

[image: android]

I was able to boot easily from android to windows, but could not get back to android. Is there any command I can do to reboot the tablet to boot on android instead of windows?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

use this application, it is needed to switch between the different OS's